# Averaging a specific number of rows in DataFrame array

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, pandas, average

I'm trying get the averages for the following times in the DataFrame named ave_data (shown below):

1. 5 to 9am (4 hours)
2. 9am to 6pm (9 hours)
3. 6pm to 10pm (4 hours)
4. 10pm to 5am (7 hours)

Currently my 'ave_data' DataFrame outputs the following data (please ignore all dashes, they are to align data only):

Time   ----------------------   F1   -------------     F2    ------------    F3
2082-05-03 00:00:00   ---  43.005593 ---     -56.509746  ---     25.271271
2082-05-03 01:00:00 ---   55.114918   ---   -59.173852  ---     31.849262
2082-05-03 02:00:00   ---    63.990762   ---   -64.699492     ---  52.426017
2082-05-03 03:00:00    ---   56.508333   ---   -65.489083    ---   36.188083
2082-05-03 04:00:00   ---    36.217295   ---   -59.198033     ---   2.404426
2082-05-03 05:00:00   ---    36.153814  ---    -62.156187  ---     24.779830
2082-05-03 06:00:00   ---    93.920334   ---   -57.923000  ---     77.654250
...

I would like to save these new averages as a new DataFrame that looks something like (the numbers below are random examples only):

Time   --------------------   F1   -------------     F2    ------------    F3
Morning(5AM-9AM)  ---        50.005987  ---    -60.509746   ---    29.311271
Day(9AM-6PM)       --------        59.005987  ---     -49.509746    ---    98.311271
Evening(6PM-10PM)   --       55.018887   ---    -47.614622    ---    29.311271
Night (10PM-5AM)      ----     55.018887    ---   -47.614622   ---     29.311271

Also, I would ideally like to add a last column that contains the average of each row. The code will be used to read different files that will generate a different number of columns than shown below, so if someone could help me develop a general method for this that would be great.

Below is the relevant section of the code I have:

```
raw_data = pd.read_excel(r'/Users/linnkloster/Desktop/Results/01_05_2012 Raw Results.xls', skiprows=1, header=0, nrows=1440, dayfirst=True, infer_datetime_format='%d/%m/%Y %H')
raw_data[u'Time']= pd.to_datetime(raw_data['Time'], unit='d')
# Converts first column to datetime, to make averaging easier
# Note this gets the wrong date (2082-05-03) but correct hour
raw_data.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(raw_data[u'Time']), inplace=True)
ave_data=raw_data.resample('h', how='mean')
print ave_data
```

Comment: Can you upload your sample xls file (for example, via Dropbox sharelink or google driver)? For sampling at intraday hours, a few choices are available: `.indexer_between_time` or `pd.cut` on how many hours past midnight (`timedelta`).

Comment: The actual data is a bit sensitive, and since I got a solution that worked I won't upload it this time. Thank you for good suggestions though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a function that returns the category:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('2082-05-03 00:00:00', 43.005593, -56.509746, 25.271271),
('2082-05-03 01:00:00', 55.114918, -59.173852, 31.849262),
('2082-05-03 02:00:00', 63.990762, -64.699492, 52.426017),
('2082-05-03 03:00:00', 56.508333, -65.489083, 36.188083),
('2082-05-03 04:00:00', 36.217295, -59.198033, 2.404426),
('2082-05-03 05:00:00', 36.153814, -62.156187, 24.779830),
('2082-05-03 06:00:00', 93.920334, -57.923000, 77.654250)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns=['Time', 'F1', 'F2', 'F3'])
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)

def time_cat(t):
    hour = t.hour
    if hour < 5:
        return 'Night(10PM-5AM)'
    if hour < 9:
        return 'Morning(5AM-9AM)'
    if hour < 18:
        return 'Day(9AM-6PM)'
    if hour < 22:
        return 'Evening(6PM-10PM)'
    # if hour >= 22:
    return 'Night(10PM-5AM)'

df.groupby(df.Time.apply(time_cat)).mean()
```

---

```
                    F1          F2          F3
Time            
Morning(5AM-9AM)    65.037074   -60.039594  51.217040
Night(10PM-5AM)     50.967380   -61.014041  29.627812
```

Comment: This worked nicely. Thank you! I removed 'columns=['Time', 'F1', 'F2', 'F3']' as these titles will change as the code reads different files (earlier in the code file). 
For some reason the output is in the order: (row 1) Day, (row 2) Evening and then (row 3) Morning and (row 4) Night. This might be an easy fix but any easy idea on how to re-stack them to get the new DataFrame/Output to be in the order (row 1) Morning, (2) Day, (3) Evening, (4) Night? Sorry I'm quite new to Python..

Comment: A quick follow-up question:  I'm trying to use this for another DataFrame, that has been created by manipulating the raw_data DataFrame from the initial question. However, the manipulated DataFrame loses the index header so that I can't call "Time" as you did in the code above. I tried to assign the index title again, using df.index.name=u'Time' but it gives me the following error: 
"ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 4"
Any ideas on how I can fix this so I can sort this new DataFrame (named outage_by_hour) in the same way?

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is with that information. Probably should just post another question with more context on how you created the other dataframe.

Comment: Not a bad idea:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783944/trouble-averaging-specific-rows-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Could you explain what the '.Time' part of df.Time does? I'm having a hard time running another DataFrame through this function:

outage_by_hour_num.Time= pd.to_datetime(outage_by_hour_num.Time)
outage_by_timeofday =outage_by_hour_num.groupby(outage_by_hour_num.Time.apply(time_cat)).sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Time'

When I call outage_by_hour_num.index, I get the following information though: DatetimeIndex( ... ) 
dtype='datetime64[ns]', **name=u'Time'** , freq='H', tz=None) - implying that the DataFrame does have 'Time' as an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Note that I added three columns, so I use `df`, a copy of `raw_data`. If OK, you do not need a copy, of course.

```
def Time(hour):
    if(hour>=5 and hour<9):
        return 'Morning'
    elif(hour>=9 and hour<18):
        return 'Day'
    elif(hour>=18 and hour<22):
        return 'Evening'
    else:
        return 'Night'

df = raw_data.copy()
df['date'] = df.Time.apply(lambda time:time.date())
df['hour'] = df.Time.apply(lambda time:time.hour)
df['time']=df.hour.apply(Time)
ave_data=df.drop('hour',axis=1).groupby(['date','time']).mean()
```